# Content-Type column default value

Tags: 2013, content-type, column, default-value

I created a custom content type called "test".

The columns are:

1. Title
2. Publisher

The column "Publisher" is already a column which comes from SharePoint itself.

I changed the default value to "afraIT" and published the content type.
I also started the process "Content Type Hub" and "Content Type Subscriber".

The content type is available in my library, but the default value (afraIT) is not set.

I can change the description. That is working, but the **default value** is still empty.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I found this link: http://sweechingho.blogspot.de/2008/07/sharepoint-site-column-default-value.html

They mention that you have to **set the content type as default**. Only then, the default value is shown. I tried it and it works.

**Is this really the only way Microsoft?**

Comment: Any errors in the Content Type Publishing Log?

Comment: No, but I found this: http://sweechingho.blogspot.de/2008/07/sharepoint-site-column-default-value.html and it is working. So if I want to have the default value, the content type has also to be the default content type? Really?

Comment: It's SharePoint, so no doubt someone in the product team has thought it to be a brilliant idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Either You have to set default content type to shown content type columns while adding new item OR you can select the content type while adding new item from ITEM TAB --> New item --> Select Content Type in Ribbon.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As of today (Feb 2017) I'm facing the same behavior for SharePoint Online - can't set the default value for column which is not in default CNT. Possible  workarounds: 1. workflow (set value based on content type) 2. JSLink (connected to New/Edit forms) 3. Set default column value based on folder name (the folder per content type is needed)

Comment: could you be so kind and share th JS with all of us? That would be great!